# Selenium job configuration error in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, protractor

I am just integrating Protractor end to end test job in my Jenkins. Jenkins is running on CentOS 7. With the help of one of my test engineer created a config.js file and created a Jenkins job for the same.

I am getting the following error in Jenkins console while executing this job:

```
+ cd '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/UI Automation Test/UI-automation-tests/Test/steps'
+ protractor config.js
(node:11138) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[07:12:43] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[07:12:43] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[07:12:43] W/launcher - Ignoring uncaught error WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609551 (5d576e9a44fe4c5b6a07e568f1ebc753f1214634),platform=Linux 3.10.0-862.2.3.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug of ChromeDriver (already reported). For Linux systems you can use this argument to avoid this error:

```
--disable-dev-shm-usage
```